# Finding distinct naturals $a$ and $b$ such that $\sigma(a)=\sqrt b$ and $\sigma(b)=\sqrt a$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of $n$'s decimal digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Consider two natural numbers $a$, $b$, where $a\neq b$ which satisfy $$\sigma(a) = \sqrt b$$ $$\sigma(b) =  \sqrt a$$ where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of digits of $n$ in decimal radix.
>
> I need to determine $a$ and $b$.

$$\bmod 9: \\\\ a \equiv \sqrt b \\\\ b \equiv \sqrt a$$

According to WolframAlpha, this system of congruences has solution

$$(a,b) \equiv (16+81k^2+72k,49+81k^2+126k) \ \ k \in Z$$
and putting $k=1$ only yields correct pair of $(a,b)$ as far as I have tried. Why is that so, and how to show the condition holds for only $k=1$?

Alternate approaches are welcome as well.

Comment: Maybe $\sigma(a)<9(1+\log_{10}(a))$ helps.

Comment: I tried but failed to find any simple expression.

Comment: Consider thinking of @GerryMyerson's comment as a boundary rather than a direct path to solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose positive integers $a,b$ satisfy the equations.
$$
\sigma(a)=\sqrt{b}\\
\sigma(b)=\sqrt{a}
$$
Without loss of generality assume $a\le b$.

Then letting $m,n$ be the number of decimal digits of $a,b$, respectively, we have
$$
10^{m-1}\le a < 10^m\\
10^{n-1}\le b < 10^n.
$$
so we get
$$
9m\ge\sigma(a)=\sqrt{b}\ge 10^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\ge 10^{\frac{m-1}{2}}\\
$$
which gives$\;81m^2\ge 10^{m-1}$.

But an easy induction shows that $81m^2 < 10^{m-1}$ for all $m\ge 5$, hence $m\le 4$.

Then
$$
m\le 4
\implies
36\ge\sigma(a)
\implies
36\ge\sqrt{b}
\implies
36^2\ge b
$$
at which point, a brute force search with $b\in\{1^2,2^2,3^2,...,36^2\}$ yields the solutions
$$
(b,a)\;=\;(1^2,1^2),\;\;\;(9^2,9^2),\;\;\;(16^2,13^2)
$$